# How to addition seconds with seconds in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have my current time in seconds and duration time in seconds.
I want to add both seconds to calculate the end time of the song (for example).
But i have a weird format in the result.

Here is my code :

```js
// This is my song's duration
var duration = new Date("Sept 21, 2019 00:03:32");
var durationSeconds = duration.getSeconds();

// Current second
var date = new Date();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
var differenceSecondsConverted = date.setSeconds(seconds + durationSeconds);

console.log(differenceSecondsConverted);
```

And the result is something like : 1569102592740

Thanks

Comment: `.setSeconds()` updates the date then returns the ms since the epoc. Instead of writing out the return value, write the `date` itself after the function call.

Comment: Thanks. I removed "setSeconds()", but now, seconds are going up to 90 :/

Comment: First, review https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. Since the Date is milliseconds since the epoc, you can add the appropriate number of milliseconds to this value to find your end time. Then use the new value to construct the next Date instance `new Date(ms)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code works as it should, probably, you just miss some concept.

The `new Date()` is a constructor that returns an instance of `Date` object.

This object have several properties. When you instantiate it, it returns something like `Sun Sep 22 2019 01:21:14 GMT+0200 (CEST)` which is string representation of current time.

However, this string representation is not how JS actually "thinks" about the time.

Internally, "time" for JS is number of milliseconds passed from January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.

It looks something like this: `1569108461979`.

You may see it if you run `Date.now();`

Also, if you do any calculations (not directly, but using methods like `.setDate`) with `new Date()`, it will be internally calculated as milliseconds passed from  1, 1970, 00:00:00.

So, the main problem in your code is that your `duration` variable is not actually "duration".

It just contains an object that represents Sept 21, 2019 00:03:32.

It is just a moment in time (3 minutes, 32 seconds after midnight of 20 of September 2019).

To calculate when the song will end if it starts right now, you'd do something like:

```
let now = Date.now();
// Song duration in milliseconds
let songDuration = 201000;

let songEndTime = now + songDuration;

console.log( new Date(songEndTime) );
```

Comment: @SachaCOHEN Glad to help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a date object for the time in say 3:32 by adding 3 minutes and 32 seconds to the current date, e.g.

```js
// time is minutes and seconds as mm:ss
function nowPlus(time) {
  let [m, s] = time.split(':').map(Number);
  let now = new Date();
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + m, now.getSeconds() + s);
  return now;
}

console.log('In 3:32 it will be: ' + nowPlus('3:32').toLocaleString(undefined, {hour12:false, hour: 'numeric', minute:'2-digit', second:'2-digit'}));
```